# Unable to join elements from the secondary table

Tags: mysql

I have two tables.

**Table1: foo**

```
create table foo (id int, name string, description varchar(255));
```

Data of foo looks like:

```
1, foo1, fooooo1111
2, foo2, fooooo2222
3, foo3, fooooo3333
4, foo4, fooooo4444
```

**Table2: bar**

```
create table bar (foo_id int, value string, data varchar(255));
```

Data of bar looks like:

```
foo1, bar11, {"event":"test"}

foo1, bar22, {"event":"test111"}

foo2, bar33, {"event":"test222"}
```

I want to execute the following query.

```
select foo.id As Id, foo.name As Name, bar.* As b from foo LEFT JOIN bar on foo.Id = bar.foo_id;
```

When I set the column bar.* As b it fails to fetch the data. How should I do it?

Comment: There isn't a single column called `*` in `bar` - as noted in the answers offered so far, `bar.*` means "all columns in table`bar`". Do you really want to have several different columns with the same name? If not, what are you trying to achieve with your query? (Providing some expected sample output may clarify your question.)

Comment: Something is off with your schema and sample data; it doesn't look like you're joining on the correct columns. Based on the schemas and sample data you've provided, it looks like the correct join would be `from foo LEFT JOIN bar on foo.name = bar.foo_id` . Also, bar.foo_id as seen in the given examples is not an int...

Answer (score 3):

You can set alias names of a column or a table. But

```
bar.* As b
```

would mean set `b` as alias for **all** columns of table `bar` which obviously does not work.

Answer (score 1):

You can set column bar.* as b because this is all columns from bar table, you have to specify which colunm you want to set as *b* example:

```
SELECT foo.id As Id, foo.name As Name, bar.id As b 
FROM   foo 
LEFT JOIN bar on foo.Id = bar.foo_id;
```

or if you want to get all rows from bar table than :

```
SELECT foo.id As Id, foo.name As Name, bar.*
FROM  foo 
LEFT JOIN bar on foo.Id = bar.foo_id;
```

Thanks